# Is that able to change the image size without losing image quality in WPF?

Tags: image, winforms, bitmap, system.drawing

Can I change the image size without losing quality. 
I have set the custom size Width and Height to (1100,1100) as below then I get the image blurry.

```
Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap("image.jpg");
System.Drawing.Image img = new Bitmap(bitmap,new System.Drawing.Size(1100,1100));
img.Save("output.jpg");
```

Comment: If the original Image is smaller than the size you specified, then no, there's not much you can do. You could draw it yourself, using a Graphics object derived from your image, setting `InterpolationMode = HighQualityBicubic`. It won't do much, though, increasing the size. It can do a better job when the size is reduced. BTW, It's not clear whether you're using a `System.Drawing.Image` in WPF.

Comment: Even if the source image size is larger than the given destination size, the quality of the image is losing.

Comment: You **always** lose *quality*, in a way or another, when you resize the original Image. Usually, when the Image size is reduced, the quality loss is not perceived. For sure, you don't see the image blurred when scaled down. First thing to do when you load an image is to specify that you want to preserve the ICM profile. This is simply down using the appropriate overload: `Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap("image.jpg", true);`. Then, if you want to scale it on your own terms, use the GDI+ graphics tools to draw it yourself (...)

Comment: or use the appropriate Encoder (see: [ImageCodecInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.imaging.imagecodecinfo)), creating an [EncoderParameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.imaging.encoderparameter) for each property you want to set. Then save the Image using the overload that accepts the `ImageCodecInfo` and `EncoderParameters` as arguments. You also have the options of modifying directly an Image's [PropertyItems](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/gdiplus/-gdiplus-constant-property-item-descriptions).